# What is this kind of CD packaging called?

Tags: print-design, packaging

A client has just asked me if we can package their new album as in this photograph:

[image: Unknown CD packaging type]

I've never seen one of these before. Web searches not helping too much. Looks like the outer box is made of plastic. Hard to tell from this angle whether it's square (which would be logical given the contents) or portrait in format (looks like there's more sky in the box picture than on the CD wallet).

Does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: I think the box is square and not made of plastic, but cardboard. I found [this image](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/WwsAAOSwg3FUbq6j/s-l1600.jpg) where it's clear to see. Search for the album online. At [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/George-Harrison-All-Things-Must-Pass/release/1044712), they seem to just call it a *box set* with 2 CDs. Might have a more precise name.

Comment: I suspect you're right about this. Thanks for helping with the narrowing down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks more like a full telescoping hinged rigid box made of non-bending board with a printed wrap. If you look at the top left corner, the cover telescopes over the bottom tray.

If you look at this image, it gives a closer, more detailed look:

https://bit.ly/3ybzj0h

Looking closely at the above image, I can also see the wrap edges.

The item holding the DVD is a sleeve closed on 3 sides.
All of these items go into the box.

Comment: For sure a "rigid box" also frequently called a "rigid clam-shell box"

Comment: Thanks – terrific answer! It does look like board in these other pictures. Somehow it didn't occur to me to look for this specific release rather than try to find generic packaging options. I've got some vocabulary to take to my usual manufacturing contacts now!

Comment: remember to spec the *interior* dimension of the box to the size of the largest (trim size) item (sleeve/booklet)